# how can global function expression can access variable inside containing function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is an example:

```
function outerFunc(){
    //some variable 

    var x = 10;

    Obj = function(){  //Its global function created without var keyword
        this.a = x;
    }
}
```

So now when I create new instance of `Obj` object after calling the `outerFunc` function.

```
outerFunc();

myObj = new Obj();

myObj.a;  //prints 10
```

So I wonder how can it read containing functions private variable `x` when I define `Obj` as global constructor, it still can read the value.

Comment: The scope of the function and the scope of the _Obj_ variable that happens to reference that function are not the same thing.

Comment: a bit more explanation is needed

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the property `x` declared in the closure from outside.

Here, you don't read the value of the private variable `x`, but the copy you made and stored into 
`a`.

If your question is why you could access `x` from inside the function `Obj` : that's simply how closures work : a function can access the variables of the scope in which it was declared. The fact that this function is assigned to the `Obj` variable and that this variable is global changes absolutely nothing.

Here's some additional reading : [the MDN on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: but i defined Obj as global construction in that function how can global function has access to other functions variable

Comment: @nazirdon I detailed my explanation on this specific point. Is it clear now ?

Comment: and if u could tell why is it like so